# Подсчитать сумму мест, на которых в словах текста стоит заданная буква.С++

Tags: c++

**Помогите пожалуйста с написанием программы на c++, второй день мучаюсь.**

> Подсчитать сумму мест, на которых в словах текста стоит заданная буква. Ввод предложения и символа должны быть с клавиатуры.

Суть в том, чтобы не просто посчитать количество букв в строке, а в том, чтобы посчитать сколько раз указанная буква стоит на каждой из позиций в слове.

К примеру: съешь ещё этих мягких французских булок, да ещё выпей чаю
если выбрать е то:
е упоминается:
на позиции 0 2 раза
на позиции 2 1 раз
на позиции 3 1 раз
и оформить это так:

```
[0]:2
[2]:1
[3]:1
```

Пробовал разные варианты, но каждый раз что-то не получается.
Сейчас остановился на этом, но и тут есть проблемы (хотя по сути тут ещё ничего и нет):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    string x;
    string c;
    cin »x;
    (cin »x).get();
    cin »c;
    (cin »c).get();

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
        cout «x.find(c);
    }
}
```

В общем ступор, плиз хелп.

Comment: Что то я не пойму ваш пример: что за позиция 0? Имеется ввиду первое слово? Но если так, то почему результат 2? Ведь первое слово - это "съешь" - а сдесь только 1 буква 'е'

Comment: позиция ноль это первая буква(т.к индексация с нуля), также с остальными позициями. С нулевой позицией, т.е с двумя первыми буквами е - два слова "ещё"

Answer (score 0):

```
int s = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) if (x[i] == c) s += i;
// s - ответ на вопрос задачи
```

Comment: я тоже думал, что всё так просто)
но соль в том, чтобы не просто сложить все места с этой буквой в предложении, а в том, чтобы брать позицию в каждом слове с этой буквой и получить несколько сумм - с первой позицией, второй и т.д

Comment: Если честно, то вообще ничего не понятно))
Это методическая задачка? Можете скинуть условие так, как оно сформулировано?

Comment: Написать программу для подсчета суммы мест, на которых в словах текста стоит заданная буква.

Я поэтому и пошёл сюда, обычно до последнего сижу. 
Человек который, проверяет сформулировал так, как я описал в посте.
Согласен, что дичь какая-то полностью.

Comment: Ох, я понял условие, сейчас секундочку